# UIWebView lock/freeze/hang the app when downloading file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiwebview

My app use a UIWebView to load a website and download file when user click on a download link, the app freeze until the file is finished downloading, then the app back to normal, it doesnt crash, it just freeze.. How can I fix this?

Im using this code to download

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{

if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) 
{
    NSURL *requestedURL = [request URL];

    // ...Check if the URL points to a file you're looking for...
    // Then load the file
    NSData *fileData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:requestedURL] autorelease];

    // Get the path to the App's Documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    [fileData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, [requestedURL lastPathComponent]] atomically:YES];
} 
return YES;
}


- (NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return documentsDirectoryPath;
}
```

Comment: Are you having large data to be written in directory very frequently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See 'URL Loading System Programming Guide' from the Apple iOS 5.1 documentation.  You'll want to set up a asynchronous request.  There are a number of code samples for the URL Loading System.

Comment: I just found out ASIHTTPRequest for download file with asynchronus.. Its great I think :)